# Changing order of Android default photo gallery - SDK/ADT

Tags: android, image, adt

I am trying to set a specific order in the default photo gallery for an Android app (or at least a 'this image shows first' type script). I have tried modifying and saving the image to update a last-modified-date attribute, however, it seems to be a bit more complicated than that. What i need, is some clarification on how the images are handled to populate the default gallery.

a few questions i can't answer:
Are the images in the default photo gallery ordered by a last-modified-date or an added-date attribute?
Or is there a gallery file (XML or equivalent) that specifies the specific order?
Do different manufacturers (htc, samsung, lg, etc) have unique ways they order their galleries or call their images?